# what does svn copy URL->WC do?

Tags: svn

Why would one do svn copy URL -> WC? Does it get the file in readonly mode? or it is same as checkout? I had checked out a branch. I deleted one directory under branch (name is dummy).
Then I tried svn copy URL(of dummy) .(current dir).  I got the message '.' is locked. Why is it so?

vadiraj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> URL -> WC
>
> Check out URL into WC, and schedule it
>   for addition.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re07.html

Comment: What is meant by schedule it for addition? Its already there in repository. Thats why I got confused. Also i cannot do svn copy of the path already checked out by svn co.

Comment: `scheduled for addition` means doing `svn add` on it so that when you commit it gets added.

Comment: I understand that if it is not there in repository it should be scheduled for addition. But its already there in repository. I have just copied that dummy directory. Why would it add once again?

Comment: @vadiraj- what are you trying to do? You are not making any sense. What did you delete like you said in the question?

Comment: I had checked out /branches under /home/vadiraj/branches. Under branches there is one dummy directory. I deleted it by doing rm -rf dummy. Then i did svn copy URL/branches/dummy /homevadiraj/branches. Its not allowing me to do it. It says the directory branches is locked.

Comment: @vadiraj - if you just want the `dummy` back do `svn update /home/vadiraj/branches`

Comment: @manojlds let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/953/discussion-between-vadiraj-and-manojlds)